# Нужно ли создавать $(function(){ }); постоянно?

Tags: jquery

Нужно ли оборачивать функцию каждый раз при создании скрипта?, например есть скрипт меню, есть скрипт прокрутки анимации, и т.д.
Приведу пример

Пример 1

```
$(function(){ 
   $("#foo") // do something
   $("#foo1") // do something
});
```

Пример 2

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#foo") // do something
});

$(function(){ 
    $("#foo1") // do something
});
```

Comment: а ты знаешь, зачем вообще так делают? `$(function(){...});`

Comment: @Grundy если бы знал то не задал бы вопрос)))

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, не не не, ое же не спросил - что это такое, он спросил нужно ли всегда оборачивать

Comment: @Grundy ну если человек знает значение этого то зачем ему дать вопрос типа `для чего нужно`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39223795/4928642

Comment: я знаю что означает и для чего, я спрашивал нужно ли каждый новый скрипт оборачивать ?$(function(){...}); или достаточно один раз прописать, и все скрипты внутрь писать ? спасибо

Comment: @Qwertiy, а ты не переводил этот вопрос/ответ?

Comment: @Grundy, нет. Я не уверен, что сейчас вопрос про то же самое, так что даже не стал комментарий в форме ассоциации ставить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется подходит

Comment: @Grundy, там вопос явно про производительность. А тут - на мой взгляд стоит рассказать о разных подходах, что, например, можно вообще ничего не ждать.

Comment: ссылка на дубликат не верная, там про самозвызывающие функции, ответа все еще нету